# Is there a way to reduce safe browsing data written on Mac Ventura?

Tags: safari, ssd, google-chrome

The process `com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Service` has written >24GB in the last few days despite I rarely use Chrome and Safari.

[image: screenshot of activity monitor showing evidence for 24.35G written]

I'd like to find out if the data frequently changes or is just quite huge. For that I'd need to know where safe browsing data is stored to.

So I used `lsof -p 1720` to see all files currently opened by `com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Service`. Among the usually open files, there is `/private/var/folders/[a]/[b]/C/com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing/...` containing about 27M, a 910th of 24GB.

The process has been running for 22d and 10h (=538h).

```
% ps -ax -o etime,command -c | grep 'com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Service'
22-10:05:52 com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Service
```

910 refreshes in 538h makes a refresh about every 35 minutes; 24G in 22,5d makes about 1G per day.

Is there a way to reduce safe browsing data written by this service on Mac Ventura? Over the designated lifespan of that Mac, that'd be 4440G = 4,3T. That's not increadibly insane but too much for something I barely require (as you can see from the Bytes Read).

Comment: Have you tried turning off "Warn visiting a fraudulent website" in Safari Settings > Security?

Comment: @Ezekiel the option was enabled. I've turned it off in Safari now and will report if the Bytes Written counter increases again. It's at 25.57G now and the`com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Service` is still running. I read that Chrome may also use its data.

Comment: As of today, it's 44,91G written by `SafeBrowsing.Service`. I'll reboot the Mac soon and see if the service starts up without opening Safari and if so, how much data it will write.